# Swift How to disable a TextField while another UITextField is highlighted or has value

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have three text fields: tempTextField, airPressureTextField, and airDensityTextField. I want to create a check between Textfields to get the following logic:
If tempTextField or airPressureTextField is in focus where user trying to enter a value or user enters value and returns, I want to disable airDensityTextField. I tried this code. It disables airDensityTextField correctly. But If I remove the focus from tempTextField or airPressureTextField and empty both those two textfields, the airDensityTextField is still disabled.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let t = tempTextField.text, let ap = airPressureTextField.text {
            airDensityTextField.isEnabled = false
    } else {
            airDensityTextField.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

I tried the code in both textFieldDidEndEditing and textFieldDidBeginEditing, the result is the same.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see which textfield is editing inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and disable `airDensityTextField`. Then, when they finish editing, you need to check if the text is "" (blank) in addition to whether it's nil or not.

```
class TextFieldVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tempTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var airPressureTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var airDensityTextField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tempTextField.delegate = self
        airPressureTextField.delegate = self
        airDensityTextField.delegate = self
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        switch textField {
        case tempTextField:
            airDensityTextField.isEnabled = false
        case airPressureTextField:
            airDensityTextField.isEnabled = false
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if
            let tempText = tempTextField.text,
            let apText = airPressureTextField.text,
            tempText != "" || apText != "" /// check if at least one of them has text
        {
            airDensityTextField.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            airDensityTextField.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ti works.  I will accept your answer. I have one quick question - I want to update the airDensityTextField by recomputing its value based on the values provided by tempTextField and airPressureTextField, should I do this in textFieldDidEndEditing?

Comment: Sure. Or if you want to update it live (as the user is typing), you can do it inside `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`

Comment: Inside `shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString`, you can get the updated text like this: `let updatedString = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)`